# What will the weather be on Untersberg in August?

Tags: weather-and-climate, clothing, austria, alps, salzburg

I would like to visit Salzburg during the second half of August (after the 15th). I have been there during October and there was quite a bit of snow at the top of Untersberg mountain. What would it be like at the top during the second half of August, so that I can be prepared with the proper clothing and equipment?

Comment: As always, hope for the best (sunny and warm) and prepare for the worse (cold, rain) and factor in your hot/cold weather sensitivities .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [temperature in Untersberg](https://www.yr.no/place/Germany/Other/Untersberg/statistics.html) in August averages about 18.3°C, with a range of 24.2°C at the warmest to 13.5°C at the coldest.  As the trip nears, you may want to look at the [forecasts on the mountain](http://www.skiresort.info/ski-resort/untersberg-groedig/weather/) for a better idea of what to anticipate.

Comment: Please note that a) Weather here around tends to vary greatly. b) this appears to be a measurement from the German side. Different sides of mountains can have completely different weather. c) Given the values, it's probably measured at a low height. ... As Max said, be prepared for anything.

Comment: @deviantfan totally agreed... you can't fully predict, just prepare. I was in Paris in June several years ago, and it went down to 0 C and it snowed.